# Spinner implements onItemSelected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

In a fragment i have fragment where i will a custom spinner

```
public class ModeManual extends Fragment {
TextView textDetail;
private Bundle arguments;
private ArrayList<LvItem> myItems = new ArrayList<LvItem>();
public static final ModeManual newInstance(String myString) {
    ModeManual f = new ModeManual();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString("myTxt", myString);
    f.setArguments(arguments);
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    arguments = getArguments();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manual_mode, viewGroup, false);
    final MySpinner spinner = (MySpinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    //arrayadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.my_list_item, spinner.getItems()));
    return v;
}
```

}
The Spinner class is

```
public class MySpinner extends Spinner implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
private String[] itemText = null;//holds the title for each item
private String[] itemEntryVal = null;//holds the value for each item
private String listDesc, selectedVal, crtCtrlKey, defaultVal;
private int[] itemIco;//holds the icon resource id for each item
private int idx;
private List<LvItem> myItems;

private Context context;
private ImageView myIcon;
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private TextView myTitle;

public MySpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    ItemCollection coll = new ItemCollection(context,
            attrs,
            R.styleable.MySpinner,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_spinIco,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_android_entries,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_spinDesc,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_android_entryValues,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_android_key,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_android_defaultValue);

    listDesc = coll.getStrDesc();
    selectedVal = coll.getSelVal();
    crtCtrlKey = coll.getCtrlKey();
    defaultVal = coll.getDefVal();
    itemIco = coll.getIcons();
    itemText = coll.getText();
    itemEntryVal = coll.getEntries();
    idx = Integer.parseInt(coll.getSelVal());
}
public void setItem(int index, AdapterView<?> parentView){
    ItemAdapter adapter = (ItemAdapter) parentView.getAdapter();
        Log.v("setItem", "setItem " + index + "items ");
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            LvItem item = adapter.getItem(i);
            boolean sel = index == i ? true : false;
            item.setItemChecked(sel);
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(crtCtrlKey, itemEntryVal[index]);
        editor.commit();

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

//My Code
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    //myCode
}
public ArrayList getItems() {
    ArrayList<LvItem> myItems = new ArrayList<LvItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemText.length; i++) {
        myItems.add(new LvItem(itemIco[i], itemText[i], listDesc +itemText[i], selectedVal.equals(itemEntryVal[i]) ? true : false));
    }
    return myItems;
}
```

}

How can i set from the fragment the onItemSelected? or how it should be ceated?

This is usually implemented in the fragment/activity, but i will have similar control spinners in different fragments so i would like onItemSelected to be common for all.

Comment: what's the issue then you can control `onItemSelected` in `MySpinner.class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solve the issue as follows

the fragment

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    arguments = getArguments();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manual_mode, viewGroup, false);
    final MySpinner spinner = (MySpinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    return v;
}
```

and MySpinner

```
public class MySpinner extends Spinner implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
private String[] itemText = null;//holds the title for each item
private String[] itemEntryVal = null;//holds the value for each item
private String listDesc, selectedVal, crtCtrlKey, defaultVal;
private int[] itemIco;//holds the icon resource id for each item
private int idx;

private Context context;
private ImageView myIcon;
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private TextView myTitle;
ItemAdapter myAdapter;

public MySpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
    super.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    super.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    this.context = context;
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    ItemCollection coll = new ItemCollection(context,
            attrs,
            R.styleable.MySpinner,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_spinIco,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_android_entries,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_spinDesc,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_android_entryValues,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_android_key,
            R.styleable.MySpinner_android_defaultValue);

    listDesc = coll.getStrDesc();
    selectedVal = coll.getSelVal();
    crtCtrlKey = coll.getCtrlKey();
    defaultVal = coll.getDefVal();
    itemIco = coll.getIcons();
    itemText = coll.getText();
    itemEntryVal = coll.getEntries();
    idx = Integer.parseInt(coll.getSelVal());
    initialize();

}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if(i!=idx) {
        int cnt = adapterView.getCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < cnt; j++) {
            LvItem item = (LvItem) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(j);
            item.setItemChecked(i == j ? true : false);
        }
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        idx = i;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(crtCtrlKey, itemEntryVal[i]);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}

private void initialize() {
    ArrayList<LvItem> myItems = new ArrayList<LvItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemText.length; i++) {
        myItems.add(new LvItem(itemIco[i], itemText[i], listDesc +itemText[i], selectedVal.equals(itemEntryVal[i]) ? true : false));
    }
    myAdapter = new ItemAdapter(super.getContext(), R.layout.my_list_item, myItems);
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    setAdapter(myAdapter);
    super.setSelection(idx);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implements `OnItemSelectedListener` in `MySpinner`, you can do this in your Fragment/Acitvity like this.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I now how to do it in the fragment. The issue is that I will use this control in several fragments and there is no point having the same code in each fragment, this is why I want to have it in the myspinner class